# Plot bootstrapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, bootstrap, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` (see below):

```
dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 3, 30, 64, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 34, 35, 37, 39, 2, 17, 18, 99, 100, 102, 103, 67, 70, 
72), y = c(2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 2269.1387550775, 
2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 2359.51909126411, 
2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 567.150629704352, 
781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 1107.37695799186, 1160.80594193377, 
1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 260.737164468854, 306.72700499362, 
283.410379620422, 366.813913489692, 387.570173754128, 388.602676983443, 
477.858510450125, 128.198042456082, 535.519377609133, 1028.8780498564, 
1098.54431357711, 1265.26965941035, 1129.58344809909, 820.922447928053, 
749.343583476846, 779.678206156474, 646.575242339517, 733.953282899613, 
461.156280127354, 906.813018662913, 798.186995701282, 831.365377249207, 
764.519073183124, 672.076289062505, 669.879217186302, 1341.47673353751, 
1401.44881976186, 1640.27575962036)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created on a non-linear regression (nls) based on my dataset.

```
nls1 <- nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), 
            data = df, 
            start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295), algorithm = "port")
```

I then computed a bootstrap for this function to get multiple sets of parameters (A,B and k) and created a dataframe which contains the different set of parameters.

```
Boo <- nlsBoot(nls1, niter = 200)
Param_Boo <- Boo$coefboot
```

I now want to plot in the same plot all the 200 possible gamma functions created where their parameters have been computed from the bootstrap. I have only managed to plot one function out of the 200 possibilities so far (see below).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(nls1)))
```

Can someone help me out with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the function value for the 200 sets of parameters over a discrete equally spaced sets of point in the interval $[\min(x),\max(x)]$. You can put this into a new data frame and do something similar to [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/).

Here is some quick and dirty code to achieve this:

```
# Plot curves with bootstrapped params
x <- seq(min(datFr$x),max(datFr$x),length=50)
curveDF <- data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 3,nrow = 200*length(x)))

for(i in 1:200)
{
  for(j in 1:length(x))
  {
    # Function value
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,1] <- Param_Boo[i,1]*(x[j]^Param_Boo[i,2])*(exp(Param_Boo[i,3]*x[j]))
    # Bootstrap sample number
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,2] <- i
    # x value
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,3] <- x[j]
  }
}
colnames(curveDF) <- c('ys','bsP','xs')

p1 <- ggplot(curveDF, aes(x=xs, y=ys, group=bsP)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Curves for bootstrapped params")
```

I call your data frame datFr.

Here is an example plot from this

[image: Lots of curves from bootstrapped parameters]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if it would possible to make kind of stat_smooth effect instead of having all the curves. Let's say with only one curve which represent the 'mean' of the curves. This will help for the visibility if one wants to plots the points of my dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is maybe a bit more difficult to do though. You should look at the quantiles of the bootstrapped parameters to do so. [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/qN9n83rvcLk/uyhzwliNDQAJ) might get you started!

Comment: It is a matter of finding the top and bottom curves with the mean in between and then use geom_ribbon to fill in the area in between. You can tune the alpha value on geom_ribbon so it is more transparent, and then you can clearly see the points if you plot them as well. I am on my phone, might have time to check on this later, good luck, interesting question!

Comment: Ok cool. Let me know if you find a way to do it. I think instead finding the top and the bottom curves, I think we rather use the confidence intervals. Not sure. Keep in touch

Comment: I have posted a question to see if more people can give us some inputs

Comment: @Einarsson. Here is the new question if you want to work on it. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172189/plot-the-confidence-interval-of-bootstrapping-in-ggplot2

Comment: I'll check it out!

Comment: In the 'Boo' object created from the bootstrap, there is the attribute 'bootCI' which contain information of the median curve parameters and the functionparameters of the 2.5% and 97,5% CI. This might be useful.

Comment: I agree that this needs another question, since it is different from the original one, I am looking at this now.