# Plot the confidence interval of bootstrapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` (see below):

```
dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 3, 30, 64, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 34, 35, 37, 39, 2, 17, 18, 99, 100, 102, 103, 67, 70, 
72), y = c(2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 2269.1387550775, 
2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 2359.51909126411, 
2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 567.150629704352, 
781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 1107.37695799186, 1160.80594193377, 
1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 260.737164468854, 306.72700499362, 
283.410379620422, 366.813913489692, 387.570173754128, 388.602676983443, 
477.858510450125, 128.198042456082, 535.519377609133, 1028.8780498564, 
1098.54431357711, 1265.26965941035, 1129.58344809909, 820.922447928053, 
749.343583476846, 779.678206156474, 646.575242339517, 733.953282899613, 
461.156280127354, 906.813018662913, 798.186995701282, 831.365377249207, 
764.519073183124, 672.076289062505, 669.879217186302, 1341.47673353751, 
1401.44881976186, 1640.27575962036)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created on a non-linear regression (nls) based on my dataset.

```
nls1 <- nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), 
            data = df, 
            start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295), algorithm = "port")
```

I then computed a bootstrap for this function to get multiple sets of parameters (A,B and k) and created a dataframe which contains the different set of parameters.

```
Boo <- nlsBoot(nls1, niter = 200)
Param_Boo <- Boo$coefboot
```

I have then plotted all the 200 output functions from the bootstrapping (see below).

```
# Plot curves with bootstrapped params
x <- seq(min(df$x),max(df$x),length=50)
curveDF <- data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 3,nrow = 200*length(x)))

for(i in 1:200)
{
  for(j in 1:length(x))
  {
    # Function value
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,1] <- Param_Boo[i,1]*(x[j]^Param_Boo[i,2])*(exp(Param_Boo[i,3]*x[j]))
    # Bootstrap sample number
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,2] <- i
    # x value
    curveDF[j+(i-1)*200,3] <- x[j]
  }
}
colnames(curveDF) <- c('ys','bsP','xs')

p1 <- ggplot(curveDF, aes(x=xs, y=ys, group=bsP)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Curves for bootstrapped params")
```

However, the visibility of this plot is not nice if someone wants to add the points of my dataframe on the plot. Therefore,I was wondering if it was possible to plot one curve (the mean of the 200 curves for instance) with the upper and lower confidence interval (or something else). Visually it will look a bit like the picture (top right) below. 
[image]

Can someone help me out with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want confidence bands or prediction bands around the curve? Because these are two different things. I'll assume you mean confidence bands based on the bootstrap for the parameters.

Comment: Yeah it is the confidence bands. For instance, the object 'Boo' in the code above provides you the function parameters (A,B and K) of the CIs and of the median function. This are the three curves that I would like to use.

Comment: I am writing an answer, it will come in ~15-20 minutes.

Comment: Asking for code help is off topic here. These questions belong on [SO].

Comment: I think this is not necessarily a code question, it is also a matter of whether bootstrapping is relevant here IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [this blog post](https://quantitativeconservationbiology.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/confidence-interval-for-a-model-fitted-with-nls-in-r/) to get started. Apparently it needs some work around to get these confidence intervals for nonlinear models. These are not based on the bootstrapped samples but the Hessian around the optimum in the parameter space.

Your given data set may also be a bit small to justify using bootstrap on it, (which is a large sample asymptotic method).

Here is some code to generate the upper and lower 95% values:

```
library(nls2)
as.lm.nls <- function(object, ...) {
  if (!inherits(object, "nls")) {
    w <- paste("expected object of class nls but got object of class:",
               paste(class(object), collapse = " "))
    warning(w)
  }

  gradient <- object$m$gradient()
  if (is.null(colnames(gradient))) {
    colnames(gradient) <- names(object$m$getPars())
  }

  response.name <- if (length(formula(object)) == 2) "0" else
    as.character(formula(object)[[2]])

  lhs <- object$m$lhs()
  L <- data.frame(lhs, gradient)
  names(L)[1] <- response.name

  fo <- sprintf("%s ~ %s - 1", response.name,
            paste(colnames(gradient), collapse = "+"))
  fo <- as.formula(fo, env = as.proto.list(L))

  do.call('lm', list(fo, offset = substitute(fitted(object))))
}
# Calculate the confidence interval
predCI <- predict(as.lm.nls(nls1), interval = 'confidence', level = 0.95)
# Make the predictions on our defined x
pred1 <- approx(datFr$x, predCI[, 1], xout = x) ## fitted values
pred2 <- approx(datFr$x, predCI [, 2], xout = x) ## lower CI
pred3 <- approx(datFr$x, predCI[, 3], xout = x) ## upper CI
```

Now we plot this with ggplot

```
# Put this into a data frame
predVals <- data.frame(x=x, fit=pred1$y,lower=pred2$y,upper=pred3$y)
# Plot using ggplot
ggplot(predVals, aes(x, fit,lower,upper)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit,color='Fitted Model'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = lower,color='Lower confidence band'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = upper,color='Upper condifence band'))+
  ggtitle('Confidence intervals for parameters')+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper,alpha=0.05))+
  geom_point(data=datFr, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

The plot is below. You might want to tweak it a little. The reason why the bands are so slim is because they are confidence bands for the parameters in the models. The prediction intervals will probably be quite a lot wider.

[image: Curve with confidence bands and data]

Edit: The title of the plot should be confidence bands, not intervals...

Comment: If you look at the histograms of the bootstrapped parameters, (taking 1000 samples), you can see that the histogram for $k$ is almost bi-modal. Also the histogram for $A$ is close to being bi-modal. It is like the model is jumping between two states. You can also see it in the data, the way it is either above or below in the middle. Maybe this is some additional effect that can be modeled.

Comment: Thanks. So at the end you cannot use the outputs of the bootstrapping?

Comment: You can in some sense. The fact that the histograms of some of the parameters are bimodal gives a hint that maybe this could be modelled better with more information. 

Otherwise I think that the intervals given are marginal intervals, so it would make sense to produce three plots, one for each parameter. I am not sure whether you are getting the right CIs if you take the 97.5% quantile for each, and the 2.5% quantile for each.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. Bottom line, you suggest to me that it is better to use the as.lm.nls function to compute CI than use the bootstrap approach, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! That is my point. But the as.lm.nls function is only used because of the issues of getting the CIs out of R for non-linear models.